# How to make this type material (shiny steel plate of a kitchen sink) in Blender

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes, pbr

*[image: emphasized text]*

[image]
How to make the outside material of a sink in a blender and the inside like steel. I have basic knowledge of blender materials and nodes. I tried a lot, but I couldn't make it look the same as the picture shown below. Anyone who could help us out to make this material?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If you don't need to do it procedurally you can use a texture that you'll plug into the Roughness input of the Principled BSDF (and of course push the Metallic value up to 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a material for the inner faces, and another one for the outer faces. Use 2 different image textures, a clean one for the inner faces, a dirty one for the outer faces, plug the node into a *ColorRamp* in order to control the contrast and the glossiness, plug the *ColorRamp* into the *Roughness* input of the *Principled BSDF*. Put the *Metallic* value at 1. You can also choose a grey as *Base Color*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sir. I would like to ask another doubt. I am trying to add two different materials to the inner and outer sides of the sink, but it appears there is only one material in both the outer and inner sides. I added a mixer shader and a geometry node backfacing, but I could not add two materials. I am sharing a screenshot of my work.

Comment: If you have thickness you can simply give 2 different materials, if you don't have thickness you can use the backfacing, yes, maybe share your file